# Open "Launch App" menu programmatically. Huawei Emui devices

Tags: android-intent, android-permissions, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

After updating to EMUI 12.0.0.220 on the huawei p40 lite phone, the
possibility to programmatically open the "launch applications" settings item disappeared, which provided the opportunity to manually control the launch of the application. But there is still such an possibility on Honor 30i.
Intent("com.huawei.system manager.startupmgr.ui.StartupNormalAppListActivity"), which allowed this to be done, now requests the permission "com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT". This permission is written in the manifest, but it does not solve the problem. when I want to launch an activity with this intent, an exception occurs, which just requests this permission.
Has Huawei removed this feature in the new EMUI update?